# Is the timing of MATLAB reliable? If yes, can we reproduce the performance with julia, fortran, etc.?

Tags: performance, matlab, math, julia, vectorization

Originally this is a problem coming up [in mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261325/1871), but since multiple programming languages have involved in the discussion, I think it's better to rephrase it a bit and post it here.

In short, [michalkvasnicka](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261344/1871) found that in the following MATLAB sample

```matlab
s = 15000;
tic
% for-loop version
H = zeros(s,s);
for c = 1:s
    for r = 1:s
        H(r,c) = 1/(r+c-1);
    end
end
toc
%Elapsed time is 1.359625 seconds.... For-loop 

tic;
% vectorized version
c = 1:s;
r = c';
HH=1./(r+c-1);
toc
%Elapsed time is 0.047916 seconds.... Vectorized

isequal(H,HH)
```

the vectorized code piece is more than 25 times faster than the pure for-loop code piece. Though I don't have access to MATLAB so cannot test the sample myself, the timing `1.359625` seems to suggest it's tested on an average PC, just as mine.

But I cannot reproduce the timing with other languages like fortran or julia! (We know, both of them are famous for their performance of numeric calculation. Well, I admit I'm by no means an expert of fortran or julia. )

The followings are the samples I used for test. I'm using a laptop with i7-8565U CPU, Win 10.

### fortran

fortran code is compiled with gfortran (TDM-GCC-10.3.0-2, with compile option -Ofast).

```fortran
program tst
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
implicit none
integer,parameter::s=15000
integer::r,c
real(real64)::hmn(s,s)
do r=1,s
    do c=1, s
        hmn(r,c)=1._real64/(r + c - 1)
    end do 
end do
print *, hmn(s,s)
end program
```

compilation timing: `0.2057823` seconds
execution timing: `0.7179657` seconds

### julia

Version of julia is 1.6.3.

```julia
@time (s=15000; Hmm=[1. /(r+c-1) for r=1:s,c=1:s];)
```

Timing: `0.7945998` seconds

Here comes the question:

1. Is the timing of MATLAB reliable?
2. If the answer to 1st question is yes, then how can we reproduce the performance (for 2 GHz CPU, the timing should be around `0.05` seconds) with julia, fortran, or any other programming languages?

Comment: `tic`/`toc` could be replaced with `timeit()` for more robust benchmarking, but that just averages multiple runs. Other than that "reliable" is subjective, sure `tic`/`toc` time stuff, what are you trying to determine about the reliability?  Why do you expect a given execution time for one language based on the execution time of other languages? FWIW I can reproduce the MATLAB timings, the vectorised version is significantly faster - not sure why you wouldn't expect that?

Comment: @Wolfie Well, sorry, I'm not sure if I've understood your question, but MATLAB, fortran, julia are all famous for numeric calculations, and all the samples are for the same purpose. (Generate a matrix whose general term is `1. /(r+c-1)`. ) I think it's natural to expect that their performances are about the same when the samples are fully optimized?

Comment: @francescalus Er… why is the tag [fortran] removed? I did test the problem with fortran and included a fortran sample in the question.

Comment: There is a Fortran sample, but no obvious Fortran question. Maybe I've missed it, but the question is about Matlab not Fortran. If you feel the question has a particular Fortran aspect to address then feel free to add that tag back (but please clarify what you want a Fortran answer to detail). Note that a decent Fortran optimizing compiler can convert that code sample to something pretty trivial.

Comment: @francescalus Hmm… OK, I admit now the question isn't that related to julia or fortran, because Wolfie's answer proves that the answer to my first question is "No".

Comment: "No" would be subjective as I said before I think? `tic`/`toc` is _reliably_ measuring execution time but we must understand what is happening during execution. Then the answer to your second question is simply _you can reproduce the performance benchmarks by running MATLAB from a "cold-start" with a clear workspace_

Comment: In your Fortran code, swapping the loops should provide a significant speedup.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Do you mean changing `do r=1,s    do c=1, s` to `do c=1,s    do r=1, s`? This doesn't seem to be necessary when compile option -Ofast is set. It does speed up the code when -O2 is set, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tic`/`toc` should be fine, but it looks like the timing is being skewed by memory pre-allocation.

I can reproduce similar timings to your MATLAB example, however

- On first run (`clear` workspace)

  - Loop approach takes 2.08 sec
  - Vectorised approach takes 1.04 sec
  - Vectorisation saves 50% execution time
- On second run (workspace not cleared)

  - Loop approach takes 2.55 sec
  - Vectorised approach takes 0.065 sec
  - Vectorisation "saves" 97.5% execution time

My guess would be that since the loop approach explicitly creates a new matrix via `zeros`, the memory is reallocated from scratch on every run and you don't see the speed improvement on subsequent runs.

However, when `HH` remains in memory and the `HH=___` line outputs a matrix of the same size, I suspect MATLAB is doing some clever memory allocation to speed up the operation.

We can prove this theory with the following test:

```
Test Num  |  Workspace cleared  |    s    |  Loop (sec)  |  Vectorised (sec) 
    1     |       Yes           |  15000  |    2.10      |       1.41
    2     |        No           |  15000  |    2.73      |       0.07
    3     |        No           |  15000  |    2.50      |       0.07
    4     |        No           |  15001  |    2.74      |       1.73
```

See the variation between tests 2 and 3, this is why `timeit` would have been helpful for an average runtime (see footnote). The difference in output sizes between tests 3 and 4 are pretty small, but the execution time returns to a similar magnitude of that in test 1 for the vectorised approach, suggesting that the re-allocation to create `HH` costs most of the time.

---

Footnote: `tic`/`toc` timings in MATLAB can be improved by using the in-built `timeit` function, which essentially takes an average over several runs. One interesting thing to observe from the workings of `timeit` though is that it explicitly "warms up" (quoting a comment) the `tic`/`toc` function by calling it a couple of times. You can see when running `tic`/`toc` a few times from a clear workspace (with no intermediate code) that the first call takes longer than subsequent calls, as there must be some overhead for getting the timer initialised.

Comment: Did you put the code in a function M-file? Or are you copy-pasting to the command window? The two will give wildly different timings because the JIT doesn’t get used in the second case. Also, given the large fluctuation in timing, it looks to me that you’re seeing the effect of other stuff happening on your system at the same time. This is one of the reasons to use `timeit`, a single timing is meaningless.

Comment: @Cris I get pretty comparable timing running it either way, of course splitting the calculation options into their own m-files has the effect of giving each a clear private workspace so you don't see the memory-related speed jump on subsequent runs, otherwise I can reproduce it when using a function, script, or "CTRL+Enter" to run section. Indeed I would recommend `timeit`, I _think_ my point here was more for orders of magnitude than a precise method comparison, hopefully even with the fluctuations the points stand (i.e. approx. 2.5sec vs 1.5sec vs 0.1sec). Ran many times while testing.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add on the Julia side - make sure you use `BenchmarkTools`to benchmark, wrap the code you want to benchmark in functions so as not to benchmark in global scope, and interpolate any variables you pass to `@btime`.

Here's how I would do it:

```
julia> s = 15_000;

julia> function f_loop!(H)
           for c ∈ 1:size(H, 1)
               for r ∈ 1:size(H, 1)
                   H[r, c] = 1 / (r + c - 1)
               end
           end
       end
f_loop! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function f_vec!(H)
           c = 1:size(H, 1)
           r = c'
           H .= 1 ./ (r .+ c .- 1)
       end
f_vec! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> H = zeros(s, s);

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime f_loop!($H);
  625.891 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> H = zeros(s, s);

julia> @btime f_vec!($H);
  625.248 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

So both versions come in at the same time, which is what I'd expect for such a straightforward operation where a properly type-inferred code should compile down to roughly the same machine code.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that the following modified benchmark could bring some new light to the problem:

```
s = 15000;

tic
% for-loop version
H = zeros(s,s);
for i =1:10
  for c = 1:s
    for r = 1:s
        H(r,c) = H(r,c) + 1/(r+c-1+i);
    end
  end
end
toc

tic;
% vectorized version
HH = zeros(s,s);
c = 1:s;
r = c';
for i=1:10
   HH= HH + 1./(r+c-1+i);
end
toc

isequal(H,HH)
```

In this case any kind of "cashing" is avoided by changing of matrix H (HH) at each for-loop (over "i") iteration.

In this case we get:

```
Elapsed time is 3.737275 seconds. (for-loop)
Elapsed time is 1.143387 seconds. (vectorized)
```

So, there is still performance improvement (~ 3x) due to the vectorization, which is probably done by implicit multi-threading implementation of vectorized Matlab commands.

Yes, tic/toc vs timeit is not strictly consistent, but the overall timing functionality is very similar.

Comment: This new benchmark conflates two things - the initial memory allocation and the element-wise operation to get each value. My answer showed that the memory allocation was a pretty big overhead for the vec approach, and you're only doing that once in each case despite doing the element-wise calculation 10 times each. You could move the `i` loop around the entire benchmark (since all that does is give us multiple tests to average) and immediately inside the loop use `clearvars -except i` to clear all variables in the calcs. This gives results much more in line with mine - approx a 2x difference.

Comment: In this context, the term is `caching` rather than `cashing`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this, here is a simple python script which does the vectorized operation with numpy:

```
from timeit import default_timer
import numpy as np

s = 15000

start = default_timer()
# for-loop
H = np.zeros([s, s])
for c in range(1, s):
    for r in range(1, s):
        H[r, c] = 1 / (r + c - 1)
end = default_timer()
print(end - start)

start = default_timer()
# vectorized
c = np.arange(1, s).reshape([1, -1])
r = c.T
HH = 1 / (c + r - 1)
end = default_timer()
print(end - start)
```

for-loop:   32.94566780002788 seconds
vectorized: 0.494859800033737 seconds

While the for-loop version is terribly slow, the vectorized version is faster than the posted fortran/julia times. Numpy internally tries to use special SIMD hardware instructions to speed up arithmetic on vectors, which can make a significant difference. It's possible that the fortran/julia compilers weren't able to generate those instructions from the provided code, but numpy/matlab were able to. However, Matlab is still about 10x faster than the numpy code, which I don't think would be explained by better use of SIMD instructions. Instead, they may also be using multiple threads to parallelize the computation, since the matrix is fairly large.

Ultimately, I think the matlab numbers are plausible, but I'm not sure exactly how they're getting their speedup.

Comment: The timing of your python sample on my laptop is, for-loop: around 60 seconds, vectorized: around 1.1 seconds. It doesn't beat fortran/julia. (Wow, you have a really fast CPU! )

Comment: Numpy is a thin wrapper around BLAS. Where BLAS is used in Julia or Fortran I would expect similar speeds.